# UFT - how to check if function was executed without error

Tags: vbscript, automation, qtp

how do I write the code if want to validate if the function I called was executed completely?

eg.

```
Call Func_Import()

'-insert code to verify that Func_Import() was ran completely-

Call Func_OpenAUT()

'-verify that Func_OpenAUT() was ran completely-

Call Func_Login()

'-verify that Func_Login() was ran completely-
```

thanks in advance,
P

Answer (score 0):

Your question too abstract to provide an exact answer.However, Based on my understanding, here are the possible solutions, I could think

**Approach 1**

```
Public Function Func_Import()
   Dim blnReturnValue : blnReturnValue = True
   If blnReturnValue = True Then blnReturnValue = Do Some Actions
   If blnReturnValue = True Then blnReturnValue = Do Some More Actions
   Func_Import = blnReturnValue
End Function
```

If return value is true, It was executed all the steps else some where broken.

**Approach 2**

UFT Inbuild method - GetLastError() Statement.

[Look Here](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.54/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/OV_Supp_Util/Utility_Utility_GetLastError.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem in UFT, how do you detect the failure, and to properly answer your question we need to understand the two below scenarios

1) If you know what to do on failures or your goal is to restart the execution of current test/ test iteration, then you can use the recovery scenario and set it to call a function from the function library on every error, that will make sure that after every failure that function is called and then you can do whatever you want.

Now this only works if you are following the UFT's provided framework for execution, and you are only concentrating on errors, not execution flow failures.

2)  If you have created your own frameworks then option 1 might not help you, because your tests will be controlled by Input sheets and your framework must switch to the next test case during executions. So what I have done to solve this problem is, that I have created a tunnel function, all other function calls are made through this function, So in your case OpenAUT and Login will be the function calls within this tunnel function, something like below

```
Public Function CallAppropriateFunctions()

    On Error Resume Next

    Select Case expression
        Case "OPENUAT"
            OpenAut()
        Case "LoginAPP"
            LoginApp()
    End Select

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ''Control will come here on error
    End If

End Function
```

So, If there is an error in any of those functions then control will come inside the If condition(because of on error resume next).

Only thing you have to make sure is `OpenAut()` and `LoginApp()` should not have On error resume next, this should resolve your issue.

Now this will make sure that the there are no errors during the executions but there could still be failures in the functions, like if you click on login and the userid and password is wrong then login will fail and for that you must implement a return value from the function, so next thing i will do is to return true or false from the function to take other necessary decisions during the executions

So your `openAUT` function should look like

```
public function OPenUAT()

    ''Open App
    if APP.Exist then
        OPenUAT = true
    else
        OPenUAT = false
    End If

End Function
```

and your `callAppropriatefunction` will become

```
Public Function CallAppropriateFunctions()

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Results
    Select Case expression
        Case "OPENUAT"
            Results = OpenAut()
        Case "LoginAPP"
            Results = LoginApp()
    End Select

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ''Control will come here on error
    End If

    If Results = false then
        '' Your function executed successfully but application produced a different '''''''result
    End If

End Function
```

You can read the below article to understand option 2

https://sumeetkushwah.com/2014/08/12/implementing-try-catch-functionality-in-qtpuft/